# RestTemplate SSL Handshake failure - Connection discarded

Tags: java, spring, ssl, resttemplate

I try to connect to a API rest from a Spring 4 application, I use jdk1.6.0_121 (it Have Support to TLSv1.2) and JCE 1.6, in the develop code I accept all certificates.
I know what in this case exist 2 posible error

- Connection problems
- Closed port

But this options are discarded, because I call to the API rest from my local machine using Postman and works fine, but from the Test server doesn't works.

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 20000;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RestTemplateConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        try {
            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                    LOGGER.info("Auto-trusted server certificate chain");
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                    LOGGER.info("Auto-trusted client certificate chain");
                }
            };
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, new SecureRandom());
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                    .build();
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
            requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            requestFactory.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
            return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("No se pudo inicializar configuracion SSL ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The StackTrace from server:

```
[24/01/2018 13:14:55] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies]:123 - CookieSpec selected: default
[24/01/2018 13:14:55] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache]:77 - Auth cache not set in the context
[24/01/2018 13:14:55] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager]:265 - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://api.xxx.tech:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
[24/01/2018 13:14:55] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager]:309 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.xxx.tech:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
[24/01/2018 13:14:55] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec]:235 - Opening connection {s}->https://api.xxx.tech:443
[24/01/2018 13:14:56] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator]:139 - Connecting to api.xxx.tech/40.123.54.233:443
[24/01/2018 13:14:56] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]:337 - Connecting socket to api.xxx.tech/40.123.54.233:443 with timeout 20000
[24/01/2018 13:14:56] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]:390 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]
[24/01/2018 13:14:56] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]:391 - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
[24/01/2018 13:14:56] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory]:395 - Starting handshake
[24/01/2018 13:14:56] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection]:96 - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
[24/01/2018 13:14:56] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec]:129 - Connection discarded
[24/01/2018 13:14:56] [DEBUG] [JSID=] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager]:348 - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.xxx.tech:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
[24/01/2018 13:14:56] [ERROR] [JSID=] [com.falabella.lib.shared.kong.connector.service.PaymentServiceImpl]:65 - UPS! 
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://api.xxx.tech/sso/oauth2/v2/token": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:380)
    at com.falabella.lib.shared.kong.connector.service.PaymentServiceImpl.initPayment(PaymentServiceImpl.java:39)
    at com.falabella.lib.shared.kong.connector.web.controller.PaymentController.initPayment(PaymentController.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3750)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:172)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:134)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1970)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1334)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
    ... 34 more
```

From server I get de Certificate using Openssl `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect api.sandbox.connect.fif.tech:443` and I get it.

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = Kong, OU = IT Department, CN = localhost
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = Kong, OU = IT Department, CN = localhost
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=Kong/OU=IT Department/CN=localhost
   i:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=Kong/OU=IT Department/CN=localhost
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=Kong/OU=IT Department/CN=localhost
issuer=/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=Kong/OU=IT Department/CN=localhost
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1549 bytes and written 389 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 00EC98B11D95F3B5987FF48CEF594588D
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: D2D3C1BB29CEDD0562EA20B0D82FC5E2A947
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 600 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 81 c7 ac 9c 06 1e 09 7c-8c a5 45 ec 7c 1b 7a 2b   .......|..E.|.z+
    0010 - df 4b a0 1c a1 7d 1c f6-50 26 57 74 0c 1c a4 85   .K...},.P&Wt....
    0020 - 75 a4 07 65 1d f8 08 9d-2a 50 cd 40 66 c5 32 21   u..e..H.*P.@f.2!
    0030 - 56 d2 8d 1e 08 f8 07 e6-cc 55 f9 85 1b b3 0c 40   V.....G..U.....@
    0040 - 39 e8 9b 60 38 3e 19 62-da 55 7a 3c 8b 66 dd 91   9..`8>.b.Uz<.f..
    0050 - 03 d1 c8 2b 90 35 93 43-1f 7f 06 61 e0 dc 5d 1e   ...+.5.C...a..].
    0060 - 90 da e3 b8 1b 72 a2 46-37 20 36 96 ac 1b f5 d6   .....r.F7 6.....
    0070 - 81 14 75 d8 e0 ce 8b 6a-55 ec 27 e2 91 b3 2d ed   ..u....jU.'...-.
    0080 - d2 63 d8 c1 52 c6 07 58-38 ff f1 53 c5 2b d6 ff   .c..R..X8..S.+..
    0090 - 83 5a 53 5e 10 f5 54 75-7d 94 84 64 33 bb 13 33   .ZS^..Tu}..d3..3
    00a0 - cc c0 72 e6 ba 11 d3 4f-5a 6b 4a 5a 17 cb 32 54   ..r....OZkJZ..2T

    Start Time: 1516811974
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
closed
```

**EDITED**

The application are installed in a weblogic server 10.3.6.0.

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: I have the same problem too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jdk1.6.0_121 have problems in the TLS 1.2 support (does't work well), I tried to use Bouncy Castle library (add support to TLS 1.2) but has so much performance problems, finally the only way to solved this was update to JDK 1.7 (have native support to TSL 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

logs show `https://api.xxx.tech/sso/oauth2/v2/token`
CN for cert is `localhost` - try amending CN in your cert to `api.xxx.tech`

If you log onto the box and can make the same request to `https://localhost/sso/oauth2/v2/token` - you probably won't see the error as the hostname will match the cert CN

You can also add X509 entries for Subject Alternative Names (SAN) where you can specify subject alternative names `DNS: localhost` or `IP: 127.0.0.1`