# karate Connection reset error when connecting to internal qa server. (dev server is fine)

Tags: karate

so my company has implemented Oauth2.0 on two different internal servers. when i try using karate to get the token back on the `myldev` server. i get it back with any issues. (with `configure ssl = True`)

But when i do the exact same call against the `mylqa` server. i get the following error

> 11:01:46.113 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}-> private url
>   11:01:46.113 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to mylqa.corp.realpage.com/10.34.208.35:443
>   11:01:46.113 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.LenientSslConnectionSocketFactory - Connecting socket to mylqa.corp.realpage.com/10.34.208.35:443 with timeout 30000
>   11:01:46.117 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.LenientSslConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
>   11:01:46.120 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.LenientSslConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
>   11:01:46.120 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.conn.ssl.LenientSslConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
>   11:01:46.126 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-3: Shutdown connection
>   11:01:46.127 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
>   11:01:46.127 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 3][route: {s}-> [private url][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
>   11:01:46.127 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset, http call failed after 194 milliseconds for URL: private url
>   11:01:46.127 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

I havent faced this issue with other tools in my mac. Jmeter which uses apache client 4.5.5 didnt have an issue getting the response back

Regards,
JK

P.S.
im kinda new to ssl and https. so please go easy on me. Also ive made sure that both dev server and qa server have the exact same configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sure that both are HTTPS right ? It sounds very much like the QA server has stronger encryption in place. Have a look at this ticket and I hope that gets you on your way !

https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/243

EDIT - extra info:

Someone else had a similar question, but sadly no answer yet: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428400/resttemplate-ssl-handshake-failure-connection-discarded)

Similar issue turned out to be missing `Accept` header: [Link](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=httpclient-users@hc.apache.org&q=subject:%22Re%5C%3A+HttpClient+SSL+Connection+Issue%22&o=newest&f=1)

Can you try the new custom certificate support: https://github.com/intuit/karate#x509-certificate-authentication

Related question on Stack Overflow: [SSLHandshakeException for a simple GET request in Karate Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47209514/143475)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I did ask my backend developers to check if there is any difference at all in both servers. they found one. and made it identical between each.

Thank you for your links and i will look into those.

i went through the x509 certification docs as well and tried those out. thing is that we have an internal public certification, that does not have a key file associated with it. i did spend quite some time trying to     covert a `.crt` file to a PK8 based key and cert file. and giving it the paths. I will use your suggestions and research more.

Comment: As a follow up question. i was thinking of using JavaScripts xhttp as a work around. 

but it had an import error for that module. is there a starting point that you can refer me to use packages in javascript code.

Comment: also i used the `Accept` header with value `*/*`

Comment: @JawadKalia instead of JS I recommend using Java code. refer to the doc on 'Calling Java'

Comment: yup i used java. used process builder to make a curl call. and got a work around working. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it was a firewall issue with our servers. thanks for your quick responses.